# CSS sidebar positioning and banner

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a fixed width sidebar with a 100% height, next to a banner which has a fixed height but uses the remaining amount of page space. I tried with the following, but I can't seem to get the banner's width correct...

Thank you in advance for any insight!

S.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="banner"></div>
</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

div#main {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

div#sidebar {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:195px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

div#banner {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:195px;
    top:80%;
    width:100%;
    height:126px;
    background-color: rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.8);
}
```

**Updated with screenshot**

Below is what I'm trying to accomplish with the above code, but the banner takes more than the remaining space and extends outside the page, causing a lateral scroll.

[image]

Comment: can you send a screenshot or a fiddle

Comment: "can't seem to get the banner's width correct" So, how should it get displayed? Also provide a test-case and many people here will help you more likely.

Comment: Obviously banner will take more than remaining. You've set `div#main` width to 100% and have placed two divs inside it. One div is of width 195px then other should be of 100% - 195px but you've set it to 100% width. Try to set width in %. Like `div#sidebar{width:20%;} div#banner{width:80%;}`

Comment: NOTE: This will work if you do not need absolute positioning for another reason and this is just two columns.
/* for centered page */
div.container{height: auto; margin: 0 auto;)
then nested inside .container have the following two:
div.sidebar(width: auto; float: left;)
div.col{width: auto; float: left;)
/* Populate div.banner with your banner the auto declaration will have it auto adjust the NESTED (div within a div - is contained unless you say otherwise ) */
div.banner{vertical-align: top;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div#main {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This ended up being what I used, I didn't want to change the opacity of the sidebar and have the banner appear beneath it and wanted to keep the sidebar with a fixed with. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that banner is 100% width but has a `margin-left` of 195px.

Have a look at a solution to this: http://jsfiddle.net/nW53u/

- You can wrap the banner `div`'s contents in another `div` and just give it some `padding-left`
- You're using absolute positioning, so you could use `z-index` to make sure sidebar is on top.

With absolute positioning, you may get some unwanted behavior if the browser is resized for your layout.

You may want to consider an alternative approach. It also depends on what else will be laid out. What is in the white space?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that because you are setting the banner to 100% its going to set its self to the width of page no matter what, and takes no notices of the space that the sidebar is taking.

You could do something with javascript script afterwards to work out the remaining size of the page afterwards. Or if you have a look at http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail they create something similar to what you are doing with CSS. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think JavaScript for this layout is overkill

Comment: Yeah there is a specific one called golden grid. There are two called "the golden grid" and "golden grid". The one on grid system generator IS NOT the right one. I stumbled upon the other one and it uses a .js file to generate your grid and always ensures it complies with the golden ratio. However, if the CSS3 specs ever get completed and finalized a new method using absolute positioning will be at our fingertips you can read about that on alistapart as well.

Answer (score 0):

add two property on

```
ul li a {
position:relative;
top:30px;
}
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/NNcVc/4/)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This will work if you do not need absolute positioning for another reason and this is just two columns.

There are other solutions:

- You just want the horizontal scroll gone this works back to ie5

  body {    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;    overflow-x: hidden;    overflow-y: scroll;    }

*Using the below method will use auto values to shrink the block level elements (divs) to your content  while maintaining your fixed-width sidebar, your banner, and the possibility to add more and expand upon this. This is a slight alteration of one of the easiest two-column CSS layouts you can do difference being most people extend their banner across the top of the entire content area.*

### Read only to understand the term NESTED

A nested div is a div inside of a div in the following case div2 is a nested div

```
<div class="div1"><div class="div2></div></div>
```

### The CSS

```
/* for centered page or disregard margin settings*/
.container{height: auto; margin: 0 auto;)
/* then nested inside .container have the following two: */
.sidebar(width: 195px; float: left; height: 100%;)
.col{width:  auto; height: 100%;}
/* All of your other elements at this row-level in your document flow should be contained either within .sidebar or .col to start a new row research the CSS clearfix  - not to say you couldn't place as many things as you want in the body column and align them by default relative to its container(.col) but I am saying for more advanced layouts and for layouts that REQUIRE absolute positioniong. Also note the auto width. I left the sidebar width at auto as well. The div will shrinkwrap to its contents. . . as long as they're square */
.banner{vertical-align: top; width: auto; height: auto;)
```

### The HTML markup beginning with div.container

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar contents
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="path/to/banner.jpg" alt="what you want mouse-over to say" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--- Research the CSS clearfix if your document requires the use of floats for a new row a content or if you must use absolute positioning. Absolute positioning is the future and there is specification in CSS3 to bring in an interesting feature that would eliminate grid framework systems. I wish I could find the link but it is basically you assign place-holders to a template and css uses the selectors and place holders using absolute positioning to style the page. In all reality abs positioning is the "ideal" way to do things. It is just not the practical way for most sites atm, nor does it have much to offer for simple layouts. --->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

***Something important from someone with the experience to you tell you so. Don't get wrapped up in all these grid systems floating around. Some are cool in the sense that they offer boot strapping feautres such as preset typography sets, however, at the end of the day all they are (java script grids excluded) are usually fixed width columns with an inherited left margin, a container, and a left margin class to move an object to align with any grid column. These are good for learning and I think standards should be used, but use media queries if you want someone at a desktop with a huge viewport to have a large fancy user experience. The rule in general should be this: "You should be scaling your grid to your content, not your content to your grid...but still use some type of logical grid" Elements just do not look right when they aren't pixel perfect. A grid ensures this, however, customize it to your liking.This is more a principle because in design there are attractive aspect ratios like the rule of thirds. And other natural divisors that are pleasing to the eye so you may want to implement them to your grid on a design decision.***